# Type Mismatch arises when adding a basic loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop, excel-2007

I have a basic If ElseIf statement I'm trying to loop over a few hundred rows. The If/Else statement itself works until I try and Loop it (which I've included below). When I run it, it gives me a run time error "13" -type mismatch. I Initially set `MyCell` as a `String` until I had this error arise. Then I figured setting `MyCell` as a `Variant` I would be able to avoid this situation but it's still returning the RTE 13.

```
Sub code_reassign()
Dim Count As Integer
Dim MyCell As Variant

Count = 1

Do While Count < 10
    MyCell = ActiveCell.Value

    If MyCell = "Busycotypus canaliculatus" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "N106"
    ElseIf MyCell = "Busycon carica" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "N104"
    ElseIf MyCell = "Busycon perversum" Or "Busycon sinistrum" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "N103"
    ElseIf MyCell = "Busycotypus spiratus" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "N107"
    Else
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Count = Count + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

I'm still super new to VBA but have been thrown in the deep end at work. I'm doing what I can and studying the basics at home at nights to try and catch up.  Any insight as to why the loop is creating a problem with mismatching would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ElseIf MyCell = "Busycon perversum" Or "Busycon sinistrum" Then
```

to

```
ElseIf MyCell = "Busycon perversum" Or  MyCell = "Busycon sinistrum" Then
```

You need the full expression when using Or.

Since you're new and using .Select this might be a good read for you when you have time:
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the issue! I will absolutely check out that link. Trying to soak up as much knowledge as I can.

Answer (score 0):

@Sobigen's answer is a good one but if the looping is failing my hunch is `Count` is a reserved word. Change the variable `Count` to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about reserved words, I changed it just in case as well as fixing the Or expression and it seems to work now. Still getting my feet on the ground and am learning a lot from just this one snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

Sobigen's answer should address the Mismatch error. Here is some help to clean up this code a bit. Whenever I have more than 2 or 3 conditions, I find `Select Case` to be preferable to `If/ElseIf/ElseIf`. Your mileage may vary, but I find it is easier to read and interpret, especially when you have `Or` conditions, the `Case` switch will allow multiple values.

Also, since you have a *known* loop, there's no reason to use `Do While` instead of `For ... Next`

```
Sub code_reassign()
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyCell As Range

Set MyCell = ActiveCell

For i = 1 to 10
    Select Case MyCell.Value
        Case "Busycotypus canaliculatus"
            MyCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "N106"
        Case "Busycon carica"
            MyCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "N104"
        Case "Busycon perversum", "Busycon sinistrum" 
            MyCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "N103"
        Case "Busycotypus spiratus"
            MyCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "N107"
    End Select

    Set MyCell = MyCell.Offset(1, 0)

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm fairly new, I used a basic layout that I had seen on another script a co-worker wrote but I'll definitely be reading into select case usage. I'm not quite sure what you mean by a Known loop, for testing purposes I used while < 10 but once I get the kinks worked out i'll be using the special cells method to find the last used row in the Sheet since each sheet will have upwords of 30,000 entries.

Comment: Do While loop is most commonly used when you don't know (at design time) when the loop should terminate. A fixed start/end for the loop, like yours,  is usually done with a For/Next loop.